# NSPredicate contains search in a string that contains number and letters

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nspredicate

I have to use `NSPredicate`for search through some Core Data objects. But the key `name`of the custom object could contains both numbers then letters. 
The string could look like:`John 1234 Lennon`or `Ringo Starr`. 
I normally would use the predicate `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Any name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchString];`

But, if I search for `John Lennon` the predicate don't return anything, because it can't compare if it contains the characters `John Lennon`, since is missing the `1234`. Any tips what kind of predicate I can use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can tokenise your query , maybe as simple as

```
NSArray *tokens = [querystring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Then construct a compound predicate.

```
NSMutableArray *predarray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSString *token in tokens)
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Any name CONTAINS[cd] %@",token];
    [predarray addObject:predicate];
}

NSPredicate *final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predarray];
```

And feed that to your query

In real life I would run a bit of validation against each token to check its going to make a valid predicate and wont crash or create a security risk. e.g Strip special chars like "* []"

**EDIT**:Corrected predicate type to work with questions situation.

Comment: It work like a charm when I changed the NSCompoundPredicate to `andPredicateWithSubPredicates`. Because a `orPredicateWithSubPredicates`will give a `ANY name CONTAINS[cd] John OR ANY name CONTAINS[cd] Lennon`. In a big database that could be many alternatives. But the AND will only give me one.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try using LIKE instead of contains, and then you can use wild cards, for instance John*Lennon should match a string that starts with John and ends with Lennon with any number of other characters in between. You can use ? Instead which would match only one character for each question mark if you want more control over what's matched.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the search string up into an array of strings and then switch your predicate to look for any string in the name:

```
NSArray *strings = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ IN name",strings];
```

Comment: With this one the predicate cant find anything. I also tried `"ANY name IN %@",strings`, but didn't work.